# How do I build code in a documentation test but not run it?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have code in my documentation that can only be run if the user has some software on their machine. To emulate this, I add `panic!` to the sample code:

````
//!```rust
//!fn main() {
//!    panic!("Not run me");
//!}
//!```

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn it_works() {}
}
````

I want to check that the code in the comments can be compiled, but I do not want it to be run during `cargo test`. Right now, I get:

```
running 1 test
test src/lib.rs -  (line 1) ... FAILED

failures:

---- src/lib.rs -  (line 1) stdout ----
        thread 'rustc' panicked at 'test executable failed:

thread 'main' panicked at 'Not run me', <anon>:2
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

I [read about `doctest = false`](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html), but that disables not only the running of code in comments, but also syntax checking the code in comments.

How can I only disable running of code in comments, but still enable compilation of code in comments during `cargo test`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several annotations you can use to change how the Rust code is processed. See [the test documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html#attributes).

In your case it sounds like `no_run` is the one you'd want

````
//!```rust,no_run
//!fn main() {
//!    panic!("Not run me");
//!}
//!```
````

Alternatively you could use `should_panic` so Rust will run the code, but *expect* the panic. If it's code that won't actually compile, you can use `ignore`.